# Dynamic Popups - Oracle Forms 10g

Tags: forms, oracle10g

I have a window built in Oracle Forms that contains a content window.Now on load of this form I want to see a number of popup windows something like sticky notes.

I have tried creating multiple windows and placing canvas on it and call it when form opens.

But now I require the popup to be created dynamically.So if a column in database is status.For the number of "pending" status I want the popup to be created dynamically..

Is there a way I can on load create these popup after comparing it with columns in the database.So in DB if there are 5 entries for pending status the window would show 5 popup windows.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In Oracle Forms, I would avoid multiple popup windows. I'd prefer instead an ordinary multi-record block that lists the entries.